# how to deploy a eclipse java project(java se) on the ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am use the **eclipse as a develop tool** and i don't know how to **run the java application in the sever**. It **is not a webProject**  and  without the **eclipse to compiler** .java file,i have to compiler each java file and reconstruct the file construct to adapt the application.And my friends talk me that the **jar file** can pack the application as the .exe and it can run in all platform which deploy the java environment. Is that true ? And are there exist any method to **deploy the java application** in **ubuntu sever**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Java is a platform independent language, you can export your application as a jar from your Eclipse IDE and run the same JAR across platforms.
2. Java applications are not packaged into .EXE files, instead you create something called a Runnable JAR.
3. If at all you want to compile your code on a linux server, you don't actually need to compile each java file one at a time, the entire application can be compiled at once and you can package the application into a single JAR. Take a look at the Oracle Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 0):

Pack your project with eclipse's built-in Jar file, make sure it contains META-INF/Manifest.MF, it should describe your Class-Path & Main-Class, and if you have any dependency you may put it with your Jar file, then you can run it on any platform(with JRE installed) with command: java -jar xxx.jar (xxx should be your Jar file name).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you need to do File... Export.. Java... Runnable Jar File